# Android: Managing KeyStores -> Moving between Machines

Tags: android, keystore

Our developers will be using both PCs and Macs to create Android apps.

When a KeyStore is generated on a Mac, how do we move it to a PC so that the same app can be edited/built/signed by both Macs and PCs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine that you can just use a flash drive, no? I'm going to assume you create the keystore using java's keytool, which is cross platform as far as I know. So once you've created your keystore, you just copy it from one computer to the other. When you're ready to sign your app, just navigate to the flashdrive or where ever you copied the keystore from the flashdrive.

Answer (score 4):

Copy/Paste through network or usb memory key ... Keys and Key folder are just folder ...
But your question raise another issue.
Why keys have to be shared accross developpers..

In android development and keys you have 2 roles

1) Publisher

2) Developer/Workers

Publisher will sign final application ready for release to final user/customer
It use development APK files that are unsigned then use publisher key with long validity to sign the package.
Publisher may have several keys but more for business reason.

Developer/Workers will use automatic eclipse generated keys with short validity(1 years) just to be able to test/debug the app on device, these keys should/must not be used for release purposes.
Each worker may have it own keys and can change it when he want

Or each worker should have the ability to sign any final APK they produce, but it can be a security risk.. because any worker may use this final release key (publisher key) anywhere and any application from your command or any other uncontrolled  other application ...